# Ошибка установки wine32 pkgProblemResolver::Resolve привёл к появлению сломанных пакетов. Это может быть вызвано зафиксированными пакетами

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Мне нужно установить wine32 (система Ubuntu 22.04). Но возникает такая ошибка:

```
root@Aloyenz:/home/aloyen# apt install wine32
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей… Готово
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово         
Некоторые пакеты не могут быть установлены. Возможно, то, что вы просите,
неосуществимо, или же вы используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где
запрошенные вами пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, вам поможет:

Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 apt : Зависит: libapt-pkg6.0 (>= 2.4.8) но он не будет установлен
       Зависит: libsystemd0 но он не может быть установлен
 bsdutils : Предзависит: libsystemd0 но он не может быть установлен
 init : Предзависит: systemd-sysv
 shim-signed : Зависит: grub-efi-amd64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) но он не будет установлен или
                               grub-efi-arm64-signed (>= 1.187.2~) но он не может быть установлен
               Зависит: grub2-common (>= 2.04-1ubuntu24)
 util-linux : Предзависит: libsystemd0 но он не может быть установлен
              Предзависит: libudev1 (>= 183) но он не может быть установлен
E: Ошибка: pkgProblemResolver::Resolve привёл к появлению сломанных пакетов. Это может быть вызвано зафиксированными пакетами.
```

Все зависимости пакетов установлены. Что делать?